# Why would a defined variable stop working in SQLDeveloper?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm doing something like this to create copies of my schemas:

```
define dir="E:\Users\Phil\Documents\DDL_Scripts"

alter session set current_schema = AAA_TEST_1;
@"&dir\AAA\AAA_DDL.sql";
alter session set current_schema = AAA_TEST_2;
@"&dir\AAA\AAA_DDL.sql";

alter session set current_schema = BBB_TEST_1;
@"&dir\BBB\BBB_DDL.sql";
alter session set current_schema = BBB_TEST_2;
@"&dir\BBB\BBB_DDL.sql";

alter session set current_schema = CCC_TEST_1;
@"&dir\CCC\CCC_DDL.sql";
alter session set current_schema = CCC_TEST_2;
@"&dir\CCC\CCC_DDL.sql";

alter session set current_schema = DDD_TEST_1;
@"&dir\DDD\DDD_DDL.sql";
alter session set current_schema = DDD_TEST_2;
@"&dir\DDD\DDD_DDL.sql";
```

It all runs fine for the first five - `AAA_TEST_1`, `AAA_TEST_2`, `BBB_TEST_1`, `BBB_TEST_2`, and `CCC_TEST_1`.

Then, it starts failing:

```
Error starting at line : 213 in command -
@"&dir\CCC\CCC_DDL.sql"
Error report -
SP2-0310: Unable to open file: "&dir\CCC\CCC_DDL.sql"
```

If I run the whole script again, they all fail with the same problem. I have to close the connection and re-connect in order for the DEFINE to work.

Ok I've found the problem now, but I will continue and post this anyway for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the CCC_DDL.sql, it contains the following line:

```
set define off;
```

So from that point on, the `&dir` variable is not substituted. I should have thought of checking in the script earlier.